# SQL to LINQ - Getting Wrong Results

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

If a user selects 07-07-2016, I want to count how many times billdays >  30 for that billdate month, for the past 12 months.

Query is this:

```
select COUNT(*) as 'BillsOver30' from pssuite_web.pujhaccd 
where billdays>30 and DATEDIFF(month,'07-07-2016', GETDATE()) <= 13
Group By Month(billdate)
```

Result is this:

1. 1784 (July)
2. 1509 (June)
3. 2986 (May)
4. 2196 (etc)
5. 5853
6. 3994
7. 1753
8. 1954
9. 869
10. 1932
11. 629
12. 1673

LINQ query is:

```
DateStart = '07-07-2016' (from a textbox on view)
DateTime earliestDate = objdate1.DateStart.Value.AddMonths(-13);

var custQuery9 = (from m in DataContext.pujhaccds
                  where m.billdays > 30 &&
                      m.billdate >= earliestDate &&
                      m.billdate <= objdate1.DateStart
                  group m by m.billdate.Value.Month into p
                  select new Date1()
                  {
                      theMonth = p.Key,
                      theCount = p.Count()
                  });
```

Results are:

```
Month   Count
1   1029
2   1018
3   1972
4   1519
5   2657
6   2019
7   1206
8   1023
9   761
10  1620
11  354
12  931
```

You can see that the LINQ query is way off.
Doesn't matter what date I put in, the result always stays the same. Rather than 12 months from starting date.

I must be writing it wrong, thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your MySQL query is correct?  It appears you're querying two separate things.  Or more precisely, `DATEDIFF(month,'07-07-2016', GETDATE()) <= 13` will always return true until 8/7/2017.

Comment: That was just the example SQL Query I was given by a partner. I've just tested, and I see that it gives 12 months of the entire year. Not 12 months in the past STARTING from 07-07-2016. Good eye, ty.

Comment: But it still proves that 1753 bills are in July, and the LINQ is getting the wrong result.

Comment: select COUNT(*) as 'BillsOver30' from pssuite_web.pujhaccd 
where billdays>30 and MONTH(billdate) = 7

Comment: You're still not writing the same query.  Your MySQL query isn't checking just the past 12 months, it's checking all history for July.

Comment: OH! I think it's failing because I'm using addMonths -13.. What if that is not going back to 2015...

Comment: Yeah entropic, thats the query I use to check the results for July. If the LINQ query doesn't have the number 1753, it's wrong. That's how I'm checking.

Comment: How much data do you have in the system?  If you have anything earlier than 2015, your MySQL query is checking the WRONG data, because it's including results from 2014 as well.  You need to adjust your MySQL query to only look at the past 12 months.  You haven't done that yet.

Comment: `select COUNT(*) as 'BillsOver30' from pssuite_web.pujhaccd 
where billdays>30 and billdate >= '7/7/2015' and billdate <= '7/7/2016'
Group By Month(billdate)`  What number does that give you?

Comment: Oh, that gives the same as the LINQ. True. So, somehow I need to do 1/2016 2/2016 1/2015 2/2015 etc... because they seem to overlap.